# java play 2.0 form not binding

Tags: java, forms, http, playframework

Anybody know why my form does not bind

Here is what I have

```
public class Account {
    @Required
        private String id = "";
  ...
}
```

a form in controlers.Application.java

```
   static Form<Account> accountForm = Form.form(Account.class);
with a method
   public static Result addAccount() {
        Form<Account> filledForm = accountForm.bindFromRequest();
        if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
   ...
    ...
```

and a scala form template:

```
@form(action = routes.Application.addAccount()) {
  @inputText(accountForm("id"))
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="submit ID"/><br />
}
```

oh and routes line defined as:

```
GET /createAccount controllers.Application.addAccount()
```

I printed the data received and it gets the id value and the action submit.

I have printed all validation errors and it seems to be on the id field it just says error.required
don't know cause the address line I am typing in is:

```
/createAccount?id=1001&action=submit+ID
```

but the if statement hasErrors() always results to true

Please - is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Please take 1 minute of your time and reformat your question with code! It looks like the ID is not populated or sent back to the server, is your ID sent correctly back?

Comment: Please reformat your code, it s not readable. Two tests to do: 1- removre the required tag. Is the form submitted? 2- Go to /createAccount and fill the form manually. Then submit. Is the form submitted?

Comment: Do you have proper java beans getters and setters on your class Account? It is needed in case fields are private.

Comment: @adis my apologies for the badly formatted code - I had not realise - am visually impaired.  not using that as an excuse :) but simply tried to copy and paste the code in and it can be tricky to judge formatting using my screenreader - once everything is in html

Comment: @memainjm ditto above

Comment: @frant.hartm that's it! thanks so much.  did not have a setter thanks again.  Not sure if I can answer my own question yet - can you put this as an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your bean has private fields you need to define proper java bean getters and setters (the binding is done by SpringDataBinder which needs this).